# Pelican Archives Not Displaying

Tags: python, pelican

How do you enable an archives tab on a pelican powered blog?

I see from the [docs](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/settings.html) that it is a direct template by default, but it isn't showing up on my blog. Is there some additional field to enable it? I couldn't find any mention of it in the docs or tutorials, so I'm assuming I've missed something obvious.

Comment: Check your theme. The theme manages what goes in the final `html`.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you ever resolved this; I was having the same issue as you with pelican's bootstrap3 theme. For some reason, setting a value for YEAR_ARCHIVE_SAVE_AS was not working.

After looking at the theme's base.html file, I got it working by adding the following to pelicanconf.py:

```
ARCHIVES_SAVE_AS = 'archives.html'
```

Lines 156-158 from my base.html file:

```
{% if ARCHIVES_SAVE_AS %}
   <li><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ ARCHIVES_URL | default('archives.html') }}"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i><span class="icon-label">{{ _('Archives') }}</span></a></li>
{% endif %}
```